# Number with all 2 digits permutations from a set of digits

Tags: number-theory

Lets say you are given a set of n consecutive digits , Ex {0,1,2,3}. You are required to form a number using the digits which abides by the following rule:

1.The number should cover all relations (ex 12 and 21) between any 2 digits from the set of numbers

For the given set, this number would be 0123130203210 or 0123021310320.

I was able to get this number manually by trial and error. Is there a deterministic way of achieving this number for any n consecutive digits?

The number will have all the 2 digit permutations only once.

0 -> [1,2,3] will yield 01 , 02 , 03

1 -> [0,2,3] will yield 10 , 12 , 13

2 -> [0,1,3] will yield 20 , 21 , 23

3 -> [0,1,2] will yield 30 , 31 , 32

We have to generate a number which will cover all the above relations.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is equivalent to finding a Euler path in a complete directed graph on n vertices. Using the example {0,1,2,3} you gave, the graph would look like this:

[image]

To find an Euler path you can use Hierholzer's algorithm, which in simple terms goes as follows:

- Start at any vertex, follow a path of edges (the longer, the better) until you return to the beginning vertex, i.e. a cycle.
- Repeat the above process until you've exhausted the edges adjacent to your beginning vertex.
- If there are any unused edges, find a vertex on one of your cycles that has unused adjacent edges, use it as a starting vertex and repeat the above two steps.
- Continue to do the above as long as there are any unused edges.

In the above graph, starting at 0, a simple way to start would be to traverse the outer edges in both directions, e.g. 012303210. At this point we're only missing the edges between 0 and 2, and the ones between 1 and 3. The former can be included by replacing any of the three 0's in our path with 020, or either of the two 2's with 202; similarly, the latter can be included by replacing either of the two 1's with 131, or either of the two 3's with 313. I'm choosing to replace the first 2, which yields 01202303210, and then the second 3, which yields 0120230313210.

Comment: A.J, Can you provide some insight when you have 5 vertices.

Comment: Thanks A.J.This is exactly what I needed.